# git ls-files, how to escape spaces in files paths?

Tags: git, escaping, git-ls-files

A whole BUNCH of files got checked into our git repo before we introduced the .gitignore file.  I'm currently trying to clean it up with:

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore`
```

The thing is MANY of the file paths have spaces in them.

For example:

```
......
Assets/Aoi Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer BackGrounds/bg12.png.meta
Assets/Aoi Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer BackGrounds/bg13.png.meta
Assets/Aoi Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer BackGrounds/bg14.png.meta
Assets/Aoi Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer BackGrounds/bg15.png.meta
Assets/Aoi Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer BackGrounds/bg16.png.meta
Assets/Aoi Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer BackGrounds/bg17.png.meta
Assets/Aoi Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer BackGrounds/bg18.png.meta
.......
```

There's a WHOLE LOTTA SPACES in a whole lotta files that I need to get rid of.

I'm looking for an elegant way of either:

- A: Escape the spaces with a "\",  for example

  `Assets/Aoi\ Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer\ BackGrounds/bg18.png.meta`

-or-

- B: Have `git ls-files` pump out my list of files all snuggled neatly in between quotes.

  `'Assets/Aoi Character Pack/Viewer/Resources/Aoi/Viewer BackGrounds/bg18.png.meta'`

-EDIT-

So far I have tried
    `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g'`

While that happily outputs the file paths looking as I'd expect, with the spaces escaped.....  When I try to execute

```
git rm --cached `git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | sed 's/\ /\\\ /g'`
```

I get - error: unknown switch `\'

Where I expect something wonky is going on with the pipe.

Answer (score 16):

The canonical way:

```sh
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 git rm
```

another way:

```sh
git ls-files | xargs -d '\n' git rm
```

Comment: I'm on OSX, my man page for xargs doesn't have a -d flag.  So that one fails.  And, the scripts above don't actually do what I want, but it's put me on the right path, and I'm getting somewhere now.. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Rachel Duncan's answer got me set in the right direction, and I've found a solution that works!  I also borrowed tips from https://superuser.com/questions/401614/inserting-string-from-xargs-into-another-string

```
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -L1 -I '$' git rm --cached '$'
```

The above script compiles a list of all of your versioned git files that now fall within the .gitignore rules of exclusion, wraps quotes around each std line out (file path), then executes the `git rm --cached` command with the modified string.

I like this way because the terminal puts out a confirmation for each of the files it's removing from source control.

Cheers!

Comment: I get that `-0` is the flag that makes `'\0'` the delimiter for `args`. Why is the `-L1` necessary there?